# Erro em Operações Condicionais na Linguagem R

Tags: r, recursão, fibonnaci

Estou programando um simples algoritmo recursivo para calcular a sequência de Fibonacci em R, tal como faço no C. Segue o mesmo abaixo:

```
fibonacci <- function (n)
{
  if (n == 1L)
    return (0L)
  else if (n == 2L || n == 3L)
    return (1L)
  else
    return (fibonacci(n - 1L) + fibonacci(n - 2L))
} 

n <- readline(prompt="Insira um valor inteiro: ")
n <- as.integer(n)

print(fibonacci(n))
```

O script aparentemente roda sem problemas no ambiente do RStudio. Mas ao executar no console do linux, recebo o seguinte erro:

> Insira um valor inteiro: 
>   Error in if (n == 1L) return(0L) else if (n == 2L || n == 3L) return(1L) else return(fibonacci(n -  : 
>     valor ausente onde TRUE/FALSE necessário
>   Calls: print -> fibonacci
>   Execução interrompida

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Não consigo reproduzir o erro, aparentemente está tudo bem. Por uma questão de segurança talvez não seja má ideia ter como primeira instrução da função `stopifnot(n > 0L)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função `readline` não funciona direito em uso não interativo.
Da própria documentação da função lemos:

> In non-interactive use the result is as if the response was RETURN and
>   the value is "".

Ou seja, em uso não interativo, é como se você tivesse passado o valor `""` que é uma string vazia. Em seguida você faz `as.integer("")` que resulta em `NA` - por isso a comparação dá problema.

No uso não-interativo (chamando pelo console) pode usar a função `readLines`, da seguinte forma:

```
n <- readLines("stdin",n=1)
```

O script completo ficaria assim:

```
fibonacci <- function (n)
{
  if (n == 1L)
    return (0L)
  else if (n == 2L || n == 3L)
    return (1L)
  else
    return (fibonacci(n - 1L) + fibonacci(n - 2L))
} 

cat("Insira um valor inteiro: \n")
n <- readLines("stdin",n=1)
n <- as.integer(n)

print(fibonacci(n))
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o protótipo dessa "readLines" para se enquadrar neste caso. Onde eu entro com o texto de exibição ao usuáro pra que ele digite a entrada? É necessário fazer a conversão com "as.integer(n)" após tal?

Comment: Me parece que o erro persiste.

Comment: Oi, editei a resposta com o script inteiro. Para mim não tem mais erro... Que erro aparece para você?

Comment: Você usou o comando cat pra exibir texto, verdade. Nunca tinha lido input do teclado antes com o R, agora já sei como fazer. Muito obrigado Daniel, você solucionou meu problema.